# iFrame removes a div

Tags: html, iframe

I have a slight problem that when I use an iFrame, it removes a div. I think the error is located somewhere here:

```
<br>
<h1>About</h1>

<iframe src="http://www.wikipedia.com" scrolling="no" width="960" height="500" frameborder="0" style="margin-left: 0px";>

<div class="center">
    <p style="text-align: justify; ">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="line-height: normal; font-family: Verdana; "><span style="letter-spacing: 0.0px">People are extremely visual creatures. That is why very few things can beat the power of moving imagery and that is primarily why we got involved in creating them.&nbsp;</span></p>

<p style="line-height: normal; font-family: Verdana; "><span style="letter-spacing: 0.0px">REDRUM started as a creative film and animation studio in 2009. Like the enthusiastic filmmakers that we are, we try to tell memorable visual stories that help our clients get their message across. We believe that having each discipline involved in the process work under one roof, creates a strong unity and achieves even better results. From concepting&nbsp;to final product. Talented people with different skills can learn and grow from each other in a collaborative atmosphere. It’s how we like to do things, and we trust that it shows in our work. </span></p>

<p style="line-height: normal; font-family: Verdana; "><span style="letter-spacing: 0.0px">But don’t just take our word for it; come see for yourself. Join us at our studio for a good cup of Italian&nbsp;coffee and a round of pool.</span></p>

<p style="line-height: normal; font-family: Helvetica; "><br>
<br>
&nbsp;</p>

<p style="line-height: normal; font-family: Helvetica; "><strong>Ede, Nieuwe Kazernelaan 2 - gebouw 3<br>
Postbus 8193, 6710 AD Ede<br>
<br>
<span style="font-family: Helvetica; ">base@redrumbureau.com</span><br>
+31 318844104 &nbsp; &nbsp;+31 634245805</strong></p>

<p><a href="mailto:base@redrumbureau.com"><img src="about_bestanden/mail.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/redrumbureau" target="_blank"><img src="about_bestanden/twitter.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/REDRUMbureau" target="_blank"><img src="about_bestanden/facebook.png"></a></p>

</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this? I have tested it and it shows all the text without the iframe, but when I add it all the text goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the iframe tag like so:

`<iframe src="http://www.wikipedia.com" scrolling="no" width="960" height="500" frameborder="0" style="margin-left: 0px";></iframe>`

Also your margin-left `;` is outside of the style attribute closing `"`

Comment: Awesome, that did it!